# If block not entered even though debugger shows condition to be true

Tags: angular, typescript

**Goal**: Go into IF block when user selects value in dropdown

**Problem**: Even though the debugger shows that the value is true, it is not entering the conditional block. Could this be because of anything in the html? There were minor changes there, but mainly to how it was nested so I could position something differently on the page. Everything else stayed the same

**What I've tried**:

Looking into the HTML

Using Chromes debugger

Commented out everything except a single line with a console.log

**HTML**:

```
<form [formGroup]="_siteForm">
    <div class="title-container">
        <mat-card-title class="text-center" i18n="@@MoVeSeLo_H1_1">
            Please Sign In
        </mat-card-title>

        <mat-form-field class="language-field">
            <mat-select (selectionChange)="doSomething($event)" [value]="languages[i]">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let language of languages" [value]="language">
                    {{language.viewValue}}
                </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Typescript**:

```
//Array for dropdown
public languages = [
    { value: "en", viewValue: 'English' },
    { value: "es", viewValue: 'Spanish' }
     ];

//Sets default value for dropdown
if (this.localeId == "en" || this.localeId == "en-US") { this.i = 0; }
else { this.i = 1; }

//Event code when user selects an option from the dropdown
doSomething(event) {
        console.log("in doSomething()");
        //if value selected is spanish
        if (event.value == "es") {
            console.log("event.value == ES");
        }
        else if (event.value == "en") { console.log("event.value == EN"); }

    }
```

**Debugger** (This is the *event* object):

value: "es"

viewValue: "Spanish"

If event.value is es, then why is the if block getting skipped (and the console.log is not getting printed)?

Comment: Is the `else if` being executed instead? Can you post the full `event` object?

Comment: @MattU : No, it skips elseif entirely. It goes to doSomething and prints the "in doSomething" message, gets to the if, and then goes to else if, and then goes to end of method. the event objkect is what I showed in the debugger, it had the value es and viewValue Spanish. Is this what you meant?

Comment: I've seen something similar when there was an invisible character within the quotes.  The strings match by eyeball but don't actually match.  Likewise, some characters have perfect dopplegangers that can cause the same problem.

Comment: @angleUr check and try the posted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not work because you are passing `$event` to the function, so the current selected value *i.e language object*, you will get by:

```
event.value -- gives {value: "en", viewValue: "English"}
```

> Solution 1:

Now you want to check the selected value from object then you have to use:

```
event.value.value -- gives "en"
```

> Solution 2:

Change:

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let language of languages" [value]="language">
```

To

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let language of languages" [value]="language.value">
```

Then your current code will work just fine!

> Solution 3:

You can use `click`event on the mat-option and pass `language` object to `doSomething()` method:

```
<mat-form-field class="language-field">
    <mat-select>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let language of languages" (click)="doSomething(language)" [value]="language">
            {{language.viewValue}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

**EDIT:**

To bind the default value you can use [[`compareWith`]](https://angular.io/api/forms/SelectControlValueAccessor#properties) @Input() property of control to the mat-select:

Add below function in the TS:

```
defaultValue: any = { value: "es", viewValue: "Spanish" };  // your selected value object

compareValues(obj: any, targetObj: any) {
  if (obj.value == targetObj.value) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

HTML Modification:

- Added `[(ngModel)]` with with selected value
- Added [compareWith] function

```
<mat-form-field class="language-field">
    <mat-select (selectionChange)="doSomething($event)" [compareWith]="compareValues" [(ngModel)]="defaultValue">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let language of languages" [value]="language">
            {{language.viewValue}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

[`Working_Demo`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-obu7qe)

Comment: Hi @Prashant, thanks that makes sense. It solves the event getting called, however now the default value is no longer working (It is not conditionally defaulting a value in the dropdown).

Comment: Okay then you can use value attribute for this at the matselect

Comment: @angleUr which solution you are using? So I can update the code accordingly

Comment: Hi @Prashant ,  I used your solution 2 when the default went away. I have mat select with [value]="languages[i]" and it used to work before using solution 2

Comment: I tried solution 3 as well but same thing, there is no default value

Comment: thank you. I wasn't able to get it to work until I did the following: <mat-select (selectionChange)="changeSite($event)" [value]="languages[i].value">
                    <mat-option *ngFor="let language of languages" [value]="language.value">